# Should we make developers from companies more prominent

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, documentation

With the introduction of the [documentation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/07/introducing-stack-overflow-documentation-beta/), we have been announced that some employees of several big companies are now part of the community.

Recently I came across a user having `- Microsoft` as a part of her user name. Is this one of those user / employees?

If so, can we make such users more prominent?

- 'force them' to add a line or two in their profile saying about that, e.g `{User X} is a {Company Name} fellow and his aim is to help......`
- provide them with a slightly different avatar, e.g add company's logo on it

I am proposing this in order to avoid case like a 'regular' user adds a company name on her profile and acts like 'authority'.

**Update**
As I understood from the blog post the case was to leverage those people. Tim Post answer makes it clear that this is not the intention.

Comment: Aren't we after better content independent of users anymore?

Comment: The fact they're employed by <company> doesn't necessarily make them the best source of information about <company>'s software. Example: Tech support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm worried that doing so would make people more reticent to make *needed* edits because that "official" marker tends to create more sacred artifacts instead of collaborative content.

The same fear is what makes me not like the idea for Q&A - it would discourage people that might have actual *better* answers than the official one from posting.

Just focusing *on the content*, instead of the people that wrote it, really is the best way to go across the board. I've tried to think of ways to make "Hi, I work for YoYoDyne Systems and I'm paid to be here to help" more prominent and it always ends up looking like a bad idea.

Comment: I just misunderstood the blog post and though there was an intention to leverage those person.

Comment: @Athafoud We don't need to identify them in a special manner in order to do that, the fact that they're creating _really good documentation_ leverages that, and our individual partners can showcase their contributions in their own way, too. But we can't imply "these people are more special than anyone else" (even though our partners are more special than rainbows) - even tacitly, it would discourage everyone else.

Answer (score 8):

## Please no!

I've yet to see any significant evidence people who work for a company are a good authority on a topic, just because they work for the company developing a product. Just the opposite unfortunately. There have been numerous instances where companies and their employees have been at-odds with the community's sense of standards.

If a person from a company can create objectively good content, that's fine. I don't see any reason their role at a company should play a factor here.